# A SaaS model application to use Paypal Invoice API for several clients (merchants)

Tags: paypal

We are working on an application, where businesses (that also have Paypal Business accounts) are the registered "members". One of the features allows the member to send an invoice to "his" customer from inside the application.

I am unsure how to do this easily. Do I have to ask each member to get into their paypal account and create an application and then get us the API credentials ? That may be too complex for most.

Instead, is there a method in which the member can simply "authorise" the application (like we have for Facebook/Twitter etc) by login into his account and then we can create invoices on his behalf (on his account).

Comment: I am also trying the same thing in my application.did anyone got Solution for it?.